# Can somebody please check where I went wrong?

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement

i'm new with c++ and I kind of run into this issue wherein the multiplication and subtraction won't work properly. I've already tried run/compiled them, and both division and addition are the only ones that worked properly.

For my case what would happen is that the **subtraction** would add up and leave a (-) before each answers, and similar case to multiplication.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

char a,b,c,d;
char operation;
int x,y,z, op = 0;
int num[2];

cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\tCALCULATOR "; 
cout<<"\n\t\t\t a - ADDITION";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t b - SUBTRACTION";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t c - MULTIPLICATION";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t d - DIVISION";
cout<<"\n\n\n ";
cout <<"\n\t\t\tChoose your operator: "; cin >> operation;

switch(operation){
    case 'a':
    case 'A':

        cout<< "\n\t\t\tyou chose ADDIION";
        cout<< "\n\t\t\tinput numbers: ";
        for (x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            cin >> num[x];
            op += num[x];
        }

        cout << "\n\t\t\tSum = " << op << endl;

    break;

    case 'b':
    case 'B':

        cout<< "\n\t\t\tYou chose Subtraction";

        cout<< "\n\t\t\tinput numbers: ";
        for (x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            cin >> num[x];
            op *= num[x];
        }

        cout << "\n\t\t\tDifference = " << x << endl;
    break;

    case 'c':
    case 'C':

        cout<< "\n\t\t\tYou chose Multiplication";

        cout<< "\n\t\t\tinput numbers: ";
        for (x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            cin >> num[x];
            op *= num[x];
        }

        cout << "\n\t\t\tProduct = " << x << endl;
    break;

    case 'd':
    case 'D':

        cout<<"\n\t\t\tYou chose Division";

        cout<<"\n\t\t\tinput numbers: ";
        for (x=0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            cin >> num[x];
            op /= num[x];
        }
        cout << "\n\t\t\tQuotient"<< x << endl;
    break;  
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at your subtraction code again.  What are you actually doing?

Comment: Among other issues, the result of the operation is `op`, not the index `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Subtraction you're using

```
op *= num[x];
```

which is equivalent to

```
op = op * num[x];
```

and this is multiplying two numbers rather than subtracting them.

Also notice that the initial value of op is 0 for these operations, which only works properly for addition. For Subtraction you will have

```
op = 0 - num[x]
```

For Multiplication you will have

```
op = 0 * num[x]
```

And for Division you will have

```
op = 0 / num[x]
```

Make sure that you're operating on the intended values (namely, x[0] and x[1]) and that you're printing op. It looks like you're printing x for Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division.